# Headless Chrome Python 3.8 on AWS Lambda - unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127

Tags: python, selenium, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to install / run Head-Less Chrome in AWS Lambda but getting the following Error when I test it through Lambda.

"errorMessage": "Message: Service /tmp/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127\n",
  "errorType": "WebDriverException"

I am using ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 for Linux.

Steps performed in Python:

1. Created /tmp/bin in Lambda
2. Copy Chrome Driver to /tmp/bin
3. Changed the permission to 0777

**Python Code:**

Throwing error on the following line -

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path= "/tmp/bin/" + chrome_linux_driver)

**Code is working fine when I am running under windows with same windows Chrome driver.**

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: "...running under windows with same windows Chrome driver." Are you using a Windows binary on Linux? If yes, that will not work.

Comment: How did you solve this issue? I am running Linux binary, not windows.. any help?

Comment: @Deysgroup could you look at ChromeDriver logging, get the log file and if that does not give an explanation, post here? https://chromedriver.chromium.org/logging

Answer (score 0):

The error might come from the fact that the chromedriver version and the headless chromium binary you are using aren't the same so make sure to download the same version for both

another reson could be that you are not using linux chromedriver and headless chromium and since lambda work on linux the code won't work

hopefully this was useful.

Comment: @anesbayram there can lot of reasons why we get exception. I have come across this error but OP said she\he copied the binaries. Perhaps logs will make it clearer. Thanks for reply.